# Texturing a cube in jogl results in black screen

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, jogl

I am trying to texture a cube in jogl with an image of calvin and hobbes. Every source I look at online says to have the line 
`gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);` in there. However, when I add it in, I get a black screen. When I comment it out, I get a cube on the screen. Any help is welcomed as I have googled this problem to death and have tried countless solutions. My Source code is below.

```
package project1;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.jogamp.opengl.GL2;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL3;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.opengl.glu.GLU;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.Animator;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.Texture;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.TextureIO;

/**
 * Simple Implements GLEventListener so that I can modify 
 * what happens when application runs
 * 
 * @author Alex Thoennes
 *
 */
public class Simple extends GLCanvas implements GLEventListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private double eyeX = 5;
    private double eyeY = 5;
    private double eyeZ = 5;
    private float o = 0.0001f;

    // this is the title of the frame
    static final String TITLE = "Simple";

    // these are the dimensions of the frame
    static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 500;
    static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 500;

    int texture;
    Texture t;

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {   
        // this class extends the GLCanvas class
        // so that I have something to reference 
        // when I want to draw
        GLCanvas canvas = new Simple();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));

        // create a new frame to hold the canvas
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        // add the canvas to the frame
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);

        // set the title of the frame
        frame.setTitle(TITLE);

        // this is not required but is convenient. When you 
        // click the 'x' in the top left of the screen, the 
        // application will close
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // pack the frame
        frame.pack();

        // then make it displayable to the user
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Create an animator object and then add it to 
        // the canvas and start the animation
        Animator animator = new Animator(canvas);
        animator.start();
    }

    // constructor for the class
    // you need to add a GLEventListener
    // to it so that you can draw with the gl methods
    public Simple ()
    {
        this.addGLEventListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) 
    {
        final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        //gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

          try
          {
             File im = new File("calvin-and-hobbes.png");
             t = TextureIO.newTexture(im, true);
             texture = t.getTextureObject(gl);

             gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
             gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR);
             gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR);
          }
          catch(IOException e)
          {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {}

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) 
    {
        // create objects used for drawing
        final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        GLU glu = new GLU();

        transformEye();

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        glu.gluPerspective(40.0, 1.0, 1.0, 10000.0);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_TEXTURE);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        glu.gluLookAt(eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        //t.bind(gl);
        //t.enable(gl);

        gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        //gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        drawTriangles(gl);

        //gl.glFlush();

        // increment the angle so that the viewer rotates
        //o += 0.0001f;
    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {}

    /**
     * This method rotates the viewer
     */
    private void transformEye()
    {
        // use o for theta which is the amount of degrees
        eyeX = (5 * Math.cos(o)) + (5 * Math.sin(o));
        eyeZ = (-5 * Math.sin(o)) + (5 * Math.cos(o));
    }

    /**
     * This method draws all the triangles as the viewer rotates
     * 
     * @param gl
     */
    private void drawTriangles(GL2 gl)
    {   
//      gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

//      gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        // Triangle 0
        gl.glBegin(GL3.GL_TRIANGLES);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

        gl.glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);

        gl.glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

        gl.glEnd();

        // Triangle 1
        gl.glBegin(GL3.GL_TRIANGLES);
//      gl.glTexCoord3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);

//      gl.glTexCoord3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);


//      gl.glTexCoord3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glEnd();

//      gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);

        // Triangle 2
        gl.glBegin(GL3.GL_TRIANGLES);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glEnd();

        // Triangle 3
        gl.glBegin(GL3.GL_TRIANGLES);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glEnd();

//      gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);

        // Triangle 4
        gl.glBegin(GL3.GL_TRIANGLES);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        gl.glEnd();

        // Triangle 5
        gl.glBegin(GL3.GL_TRIANGLES);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        gl.glEnd();

//      gl.glColor3f(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f);

        // Triangle 6
        gl.glBegin(GL3.GL_TRIANGLES);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        gl.glEnd();

        // Triangle 7
        gl.glBegin(GL3.GL_TRIANGLES);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        gl.glEnd();

//      gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.2f, 0.613f);

        // Triangle 8
        gl.glBegin(GL3.GL_TRIANGLES);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        gl.glEnd();

        // Triangle 9
        gl.glBegin(GL3.GL_TRIANGLES);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        gl.glEnd();

//      gl.glColor3f(0.6134f, 0.4513f, 0.1423f);

        // Triangle 10
        gl.glBegin(GL3.GL_TRIANGLES);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        gl.glEnd();

        // Triangle 11
        gl.glBegin(GL3.GL_TRIANGLES);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        gl.glEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: I already answered you here: http://forum.jogamp.org/Adding-a-texture-to-a-cube-made-of-triangles-tp4037804p4037810.html

Comment: gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_TEXTURE) is useless in your case. Only your very first triangle has some texture coordinates. You should add some texture coordinates between glBegin() and glEnd() for other triangles. Using a search engine doesn't help, you need to spend some time in learning the OpenGL concepts.

Comment: I know you did and that answer helped. I was just looking for different perspectives on the same problem. There's nothing wrong with that. But your answer did help. Using google and the repository you directed me to helped me understand the OpenGL concepts. Thank you